# Multiple button form with each routing to different action

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that generates multiple buttons based on a MySQL Table. All buttons have unique id and names. How can I check if any of the buttons are pressed and then check which button is pressed and based on it perform some action. Below is the logic I want to achieve :

```
<div>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<?php
$dbhost=DB_Host;
$dbuser=DB_User;
$dbpass=DB_Pass;
$dbname=DB_Name;
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (any button pressed)
{
if($_POST['aButton'])
{
$_SESSION['hello']=1;
// big logic here
}
if($_POST['bButton'])
{
$_SESSION['hello']=2;
// big logic here
}
}
else
{
$selectquery="SELECT * FROM systems";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$selectquery);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rowcount>=1)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
?>
<button id="<?php echo $row['type']."Button"; ?>" name="<?php echo $row['type']."Button"; ?>" >Select</button>
<?php } } } ?>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that.

Here is the form

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
  <button name="first" type="submit" value="1">First</button>
  <button name="second" type="submit" value="1">Second</button>
</form>
```

Give the buttons different name attribute.

Now when you click any of these buttons it submit the form to process.php

In process.php you can check which button was pressed by checking the name of submitted button like this:

```
if( isset($_POST["first"]) and $_POST["first"] == 1 ) {
// First button was pressed
}

if( isset($_POST["second"]) and $_POST["second"] == 1 ) {
// Second button was pressed
}
```

You will need to adjust this code to your needs but it should do the trick

Comment: Great i never knew we could pass values in post method. Thanks! :)